# Recursively creating directory paths on blackberry10 using cordova2.9 and webworks

Tags: cordova, filesystems, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

Can somebody explain to me what's going on here? The code below works perfectly well on Android but does not work on blackberry 10.

For the first two directory structures in the array, I do not see parentDir.getDirectory() being called, however the last path in the array ("dir/3/dir6") is created successfully in the "parentFolder" folder in blackberry.io.home folder.

```
var dirList;

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);



// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("device ready");
    blackberry.io.sandbox = false;
    dirList = ["dir1/dir4/", "dir2/dir5/", "dir3/dir6/"];
    getFileSystem();
}

function getFileSystem(){
    window.requestFileSystem(
            LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem)
            {
                console.log("Success getting filesystem !!!");
                createDirectoryRecursive(fileSystem);
            },
            function(error){
                console.log("Failed to get the filesystem !!!!!");
            }
        );

}

function createDirectoryRecursive(fs){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < dirList.length; i++){
        createDirs(fs.root, dirList[i], -1);
    }
}

function createDirs(parentDir, filePath, index)
{
    console.log("createDirs params ===> parentDir=" + parentDir.toURL() + " filePath=" + filePath + " index=" + index); 
    var arrDirs = filePath.split("/");
console.log("number of levels in path = " + arrDirs.length);
    if (index >= (arrDirs.length - 1))
    {
        console.log("Done with " + filePath);
    }
    else{
        var dirName = "parentFolder";

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            dirName = arrDirs[index];
            console.log("current dirName is " + dirName);
        }

        //if device is Blackberry, build up a full directory path as we are trying to install outside of sandbox
    var path, dirToCreate = ""
        if(device.platform == "blackberry10"){

            path = "parentFolder/";
            console.log("Paths ======> arrDirs = " + arrDirs + " index = " +index);
            for (i = 0; i <= index; i++){
                path += arrDirs[i] + "/";
                console.log("path = " + path + " i = " + i + " index = " +  index);
            }

            dirToCreate = blackberry.io.home + "/" + path;
            dirToCreate = dirToCreate.substring(0, dirToCreate.length - 1);
            console.log("Paths Trying to create " + dirToCreate);
            dirName = dirToCreate;
        }

        parentDir.getDirectory(dirName, {create: true, exclusive: false},
                               function (directoryEntry) {
                                        console.log("getDirectory callback =======> created directory " + directoryEntry.fullPath);
                                        console.log("getDirectory callback =======> Current arrdirs " + arrDirs);
                                        createDirs(directoryEntry, filePath, index + 1);
                                   },
                                   function (error) {console.log("Failed to get directory " + dirName + " Error code : " + error.code);});

    }
}
```

The code actually does enter cordova's DirectoryEntry.getDirectory function for all the directories in the array, however no callbacks (success or failure) are called. Only the last directory path in the list is processed and created successfully on the blackberry device.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue. Its worthy you try this,

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, onSuccess, null);
```

instead of:

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, onSuccess, null);

in your getFileSystem().

I got more information when I dug through and found this document: https://bbjam.blackberryconferences.net/asia2013/connect/fileDownload/session/52C12DB41EDB8F70FDF15253F02948B7/JAM847_BBJamAsia-JAM847.pdf

Hopefully it works for everyone.